# Java browsing - section handling

Tags: java, browser, fetch

While I am trying to get a html page from server, I would like to add some config to the server (eg. login with post method).

How to let the server knows that I am the same user and access the other pages?

Eg.

1. login wordpress
2. get private page of wordpress

(java coding might not needed, I think I need to know the idea.)

Comment: Generally you have to make your client behave like the web browser does. Save cookies that wordpress sends. Be sure that any session IDs or other relevant parameters passed via URL parameters or other means are saved and passed back to the server appropriately. Etc.

Comment: @JasonC O thx! So that is url after the "?" sign and the cookies, 2 only. That's great!

Comment: In theory, yes. Have a look at Apache's [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/). There is an easy-to-use `HttpClient` class that will manage cookies and state for you. Another helpful tool is a live HTTP header viewer for whatever browser you are using, it can show you exactly what is being sent to/from the server as you browse (just search your favorite browser's plugin database for "Live HTTP Headers"). [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is another useful tool for reverse engineering web requests, if the HTTP header viewers don't cut it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used the Java HttpClient [**Interface AuthenticationStrategy**](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/index.html)

It provides *getChallenges* to send and get the section data need. And *select* to send the related data to act as sections, cookies and so on.